# Centos8 dnf update transaction check error

Tags: centos, dnf, centos-8

`dnf update` giving me this error, after upgrading my centos7 to centos8

```
Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/lib64/libgdbm_compat.so.4.0.0 from install of gdbm-libs-1:1.18-1.el8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64
```

I tried `dnf install -y libgdbm --best --allowerasing`  and `dnf install -y gdbm --best --allowerasing` but `dnf update` still has this error.

How can I fix this?

UPDATE :

`dnf upgrade --best --allowerasing` results this :

```
Error: transaction check vs depsolve:
(gcc >= 8 with gcc < 9) is needed by annobin-8.78-1.el8.x86_64
rpmlib(RichDependencies) <= 4.12.0-1 is needed by annobin-8.78-1.el8.x86_64
(annobin if gcc) is needed by redhat-rpm-config-120-1.el8.noarch
rpmlib(RichDependencies) <= 4.12.0-1 is needed by redhat-rpm-config-120-1.el8.noarch
To diagnose the problem, try running: 'rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest'.
You probably have corrupted RPMDB, running 'rpm --rebuilddb' might fix the issue.
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
```

https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=54&t=73160

Answer (score 8):

it seems like `gdbm` has changed its way of packaging.

The old version `gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64` provides the same file as the new `gdbm-libs-1:1.18-1.el8.x86_64`, so the best you can do probably is erase manually `gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64` before retrying the update:

```
dnf remove gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64
```

If this does not work because someone needs `/usr/lib64/libgdbm_compat.so.4.0.0` then you can use the more complicated `swap` command:

```
dnf swap gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64 gdbm-libs-1:1.18-1.el8.x86_64
```

**edit**

It seems like we need to convince `dnf` to change `gdbm` into `gdbm` AND `gdbm-libs`. Try with:

```
dnf install gdbm gdbm-libs --best --allowerasing
```

**NOTE:** I tried the centos7 - centos8 upgrade procedure and ran into multiple problems. I had to remove quite a few packages before this migration would work. That is the trouble when files change from packages, when they are renamed etc. I suspect that now that I got this part working the rest should follow quite fine. Good luck.

Comment: dnf remove : `Error:
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: dnf`

Comment: swap : `Error:
 Problem: package python-libs-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64 requires libgdbm.so.4()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - problem with installed package python-libs-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64
`

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get past this by manually updating gdbm and gdbm-libs using rpm (and ignoring dependencies).

```
sudo rpm -e --nodeps gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64
sudo rpm -i /var/cache/dnf/baseos-929b586ef1f72f69/packages/gdbm-libs-1.18-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

You may need to download the missing package manually if `dnf` didn't take them into set of packages to be upgraded. In addition I had to remove python3-pip-9.0.3 and python36-rpmconf, again, with `rpm` and ignoring dependencies. Then I started distro-sync.

In essence, what I've did is that I removed offending packages that were reported by `dnf`, and started `dnf` again. But be careful that you don't remove something that is critical to `rpm` and `dnf`, otherwise, you won't be able to upgrade the system.

Comment: That indeed was the way that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Swap did not work for us on one server. The other when through 7.7 --> 8.0 --> 8.1 without a glitch, aside from some minor packages and GPG-key issues.

If stuck in 8.X and can not upgrade or install anything simply reinstall centos-relase 7 directly from the rpm. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7-7.1908.0.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm

It will allow you to continue with gdbm-1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the answer given by sgros was almost correct in our case, but I had to remove sysvinit and sysvinit-tools also.

Answer (score 0):

Today upgraded Centos 7 to 8 sucesfully, and then from 8 to Rocky Linux 8, thanks for some advices.

Used this guide - https://techviewleo.com/how-to-migrate-from-centos-7-to-rocky-linux-8/

On this step was many conflicting packages:

```
sudo dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync
```

So first of all i deleted:

```
dnf remove NetworkManager
dnf remove dracut-network.x86_64
dnf remove python36-rpmconf
```

also i did this:

```
sudo rpm -e --nodeps gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64
sudo rpm -i /var/cache/dnf/baseos-xxxxxxxxx/packages/gdbm-libs-1.18-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

then command for upgrade started to work but without Appstream repo (1559/1559 steps completed):

```
dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync --disablerepo=appstream
```

then this started to work (869/869 steps):

```
dnf -y --releasever=8 --allowerasing --setopt=deltarpm=false distro-sync
```

last thing before restart:

```
dnf -y groupupdate "Core" "Minimal Install"
```